# vb.net : Search and Replace string ignoring HTML tags

Tags: html, vb.net

I have a desktop app developed in VB.net. It allows user to retrieve a HTML File from database and edit it.

Issue: How to search and replace a string in an HTML file ignoring the HTML tags. What would be the best approach for it.  Has anyone answered similar question? Thanks for your help.

Example:
Part of the HTML file:

```
 <h2 style="margin: 26pt 0pt 8pt;">  
<span style="color: #e36c0a; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 18pt; font-style: normal;    font-weight: bold"> 1.1</span><span style="color: #e36c0a; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 16pt; font-weight: bold"> Request Process</span></a></h2>
```

Search  : '1.1 Request Process'

Replace :'1.2 Request Development'

Result:

```
 <h2 style="margin: 26pt 0pt 8pt;">  
<span style="color: #e36c0a; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 18pt; font-style: normal;    font-weight: bold"> 1.2</span><span style="color: #e36c0a; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 16pt; font-weight: bold"> Request Development'</span></a></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible as it creates an ambuguity. you search string is in 2 different html tags. how does your replace string tell what part goes in which tag.
even in any editor, you will find the same thing.
try doing this.

- create html file and copy your html in it.
- open your html file in browser
- copy the text and paste it in ms word(it should preserve formatting and both text will have their own font size. 18 and 16)
- use ms word's replace function to replace the text with "1.2 Request Development"

you will see that both text will be 18 pt now. you from what i understand are expecting to preserve their individual font-size which is not possible.

Even to do same as word does will require a regex or probably use some developed library.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is HTML parsing. There are MANY ways to do this, here is a simple example of using MSHTML and DOM:

You have to first:

```
Imports mshtml
```

Then declare a string variable (e.g. myHTML) and put all your HTML there. Then call *parseMyHtml* method.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim myHTML As String = "<title>hello world!</title><h2 style=""margin: 26pt 0pt 8pt;""><span style=""color: #e36c0a; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 18pt; font-style: normal;    font-weight: bold""> 1.1</span><span style=""color: #e36c0a; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 16pt; font-weight: bold""> Request Process</span></a></h2>"
    Response.Write(parseMyHtml(myHTML))
End Sub
```

You must be clever and customize *parseMyHtml* method to do what you like. Notice I am looking for all of the SPAN tags and replacing their *innerText*:

```
Function parseMyHtml(ByVal htmlToParse$) As String
    Dim htmlDocument As IHTMLDocument2 = New HTMLDocumentClass()
    htmlDocument.write(htmlToParse)
    htmlDocument.close()

    Dim allElements As IHTMLElementCollection = htmlDocument.body.all

    Dim allSpanTags As IHTMLElementCollection = allElements.tags("span")
    Dim element As IHTMLElement
    For Each element In allSpanTags
        element.innerText = element.innerText.Replace("1.1", "1.2")
        element.innerText = element.innerText.Replace("Process", "Development")
    Next

    Return htmlDocument.body.innerHTML
End Function
```